# VimLatex-suite SageTex compile shortcut

Tags: compiling, vim, vim-latex, sagetex, mapping

I am using LaTeX in Vim with VimLaTeX-Suite and i just started using Sage and i want to implement SageTex in my documents, but everytime i want to compile a have to follow this process in the terminal

`$ pdflatex <doc.tex>`

`$ sage <doc.sagetex.sage>`

`$ pdflatex <doc.tex>`

[Ref:commands to compile from terminal](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SageMath)

I want to run a command this `\ll` one which compiles the files to pdf.

I saw that you can make something like this:

`map <leader>ls :w<cr><leader>ll<cr>!sage %.sagetex.sage<cr><leader>ll`

or this

`<leader>ls :w<cr>:!pdflatex %<cr>:!sage %.sagetex.sage<cr>:!pdflatex %`

in the ~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim or the ~/.vimrc file but it doesnt work for me and i dont know what to do?

Can someone give me a hint? plz. :)

Comment: I think you're missing a colon before `!`.  Does that work?

Comment: No i tried this 

<leader>ls :w<cr>:!pdflatex %<cr>:!sage %.sagetex.sage<cr>:!pdflatex %

and still no output

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I put this in my .vimrc, it works for me.

```
    au BufReadPost *.tex nnoremap <silent> <leader>sx
     \ :! pdflatex % &&
     \ sage %:r.sagetex.sage &&
     \ pdflatex %<cr>
```